# Eloquent where clause with multiple condtion filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

In my database table i have A TABLE named student add i want to fetch the specific student who has  all the following condition stored in filters array with some other option ("like name can be middlename or lastname")

```
$filters = [
                ['type' => 'name', 'value' => 'Abhishek'],
                ['type' => 'roll', 'value' => '0013']
            ];
```

> i am trying to fetch that data with following code

```
 $student = Student::where(function ($query) use ($filters) {

            foreach($filters as $filter) {
                switch($filter['type']){
                    case 'name' :
                        $query->where('firstname', $filter['value'])
                        ->orWhere('middlename', $filter['value'])
                        ->orWhere('lastname', $filter['value']);
                        break;
                    case 'roll' :
                        $query->where('rollnumber', $filter['value']);
                        break;

                }
            }
        })
        ->get();
```

> i am using advance where clause here but it is running  for  first parameter(like name) only means i am getting value **where name = filters['value']** why it is so

Answer (score 0):

Why use a case inside of the query? Just write 2 with multiple where clauses and select it with an `if` statement :)

Answer (score 0):

For this SQL

```
select * from `students` where ((`firstname` = ? or `middlename` = ? or `lastname` = ?) and `rollnumber` = ?)

    $student = Student::where(function ($query) use ($filters) {

        foreach($filters as $filter) {
            switch($filter['type']){
                case 'name' :
                    $query->where(function ($query) use ($filter) {
                        $query->where('firstname', $filter['value'])
                            ->orWhere('middlename', $filter['value'])
                            ->orWhere('lastname', $filter['value']);
                    });//This will add a parenthesis for all wheres
                    break;
                case 'roll' :
                    $query->where('rollnumber', $filter['value']);
                    break;

            }
        }
    })
        ->get();//Replace get with toSql to see SQL
```

For this SQL

```
select * from `students` where ((`firstname` = ? or `middlename` = ? or `lastname` = ?) or `rollnumber` = ?)

    $student = Student::where(function ($query) use ($filters) {

        foreach($filters as $filter) {
            switch($filter['type']){
                case 'name' :
                    $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($filter) {//add or where for or where
                        $query->where('firstname', $filter['value'])
                            ->orWhere('middlename', $filter['value'])
                            ->orWhere('lastname', $filter['value']);
                    });//This will add a parenthesis for all wheres
                    break;
                case 'roll' :
                    $query->orWhere('rollnumber', $filter['value']);//add or where for or where
                    break;

            }
        }
    })
        ->get();//Replace get with toSql to see SQL
```